# Other module tags inside tag data causing issue

Tags: php, module, plugin

I am creating a small plugin, and am having an issue. I am using Carthrob for my e-commerce, and want to take some information into the tag data for my plugin.

My tag is the following:

```
{exp:submission_data:details cart_entries="{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}{entries}x{quantity},{/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}"}
```

The code within the tag data is outputting:

> 4x1,2x3,1x4,

Here is the part of the my plugin:

```
$tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;  

$cart_entries = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('cart_entries');

$cart_entries_total = 0;
$explode = explode(",", $cart_entries);

foreach ($explode as $explodeSegment) {
    if (trim($explodeSegment) != "") {
        list($amount, $quantity) = explode("x", $explodeSegment);
        $cart_entries_total += ((int)$amount * (int)$quantity);
    }
}
```

Currently this is returning 0, instead of 14.

If I add the data (4x1,2x3,1x4,) manually, it outputs the correct number.

I am guessing this is something to do with the CT tags in the tagdata.

Do I need to remove them in the code? how, or is there another solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding parse="inward" to the exp:submission_data:details tag.